# websphere 7 shows full error to customer on web app deployment/starting error

Tags: spring, jsp, servlets, spring-mvc, websphere-7

i have deployed my web application in WebSphere 7. this application is build using spring and jsp servlets. some times when it get deployed due to errors it shows the following attached image like errors.

[image]

i have handled my web application errors as follows, by redirecting the errors to spring controller.

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <!--Internal server error  -->
    <location>/error.p?message=500</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <!--Forbidden  -->
    <location>/main.p</location>
</error-page>
```

but it only works when the web application is successfully deployed. when deployment error happens WebSphere shows full error message like above.
is there any way to hide this error page and add custom error page in websphere when such deployment errors happens?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an Apache server (or other) in front of your WebSphere, you may use it to redirect error 500 on a custom static web page.

Since you're using Spring, if this error can occur often, you can try to use lazy bean initialization on the `remoteOMSConnectorWS` (See [LazyInitTargetSource](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/aop/target/LazyInitTargetSource.html)). This would delay bean instantiation until its first use, most likely after webapp complete startup. In this case, your error configuration from `web.xml` could be used.

Comment: hi , thankyou for the quick response. actually i'm using spring 2.5 and the connection is set to LazyInit as follows.                  <bean id="wsOMSRemoteEnvironment" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate" lazy-init="true">  as you mentioned there is a IBM web server in the middle. i have configured the default error page to be shown but still facing the problem.

Comment: actually there are two error codes shown in the error page,                                                               Error Message: javax.servlet.ServletException: SRVE0207E: Uncaught initialization exception created by servlet
Error Code: 500
Target Servlet: tradeweb                                           Error Page Exception:
Error Message: javax.servlet.ServletException: SRVE0207E: Uncaught initialization exception created by servlet
Error Code: 0

Comment: `lazy-init="true"` is not really lazy if not wrapped in a `LazyInitTargetSource` (see documentation).